# Windows alert method inside function triggers twice

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, alert

I'm learning JavaScript, while doing so I'm exploring the Google Maps API. My .htm script below runs as intended (for now) except for a bothersome Window alert method that seems to trigger twice upon execution of that part of the script. I have no idea why - any explanation or clarification on this would be much welcome. I have a feeling it may have something to do with the structure of my script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
       <title>GPS coordinates to map TEST</title>
     <style>
     #map {
       width: 500px;
       height: 380px;
     }
        
     body {
       font-family: arial;
       font-size: 13px;
     }
        
     </style>
     </head>
     <body onload="init()">
     <p>Click below to get your coordinates and display your current position on a map:</p>
     <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="get_location()" value="Where am I?">
     <p>Or provide coordinates to display the position entered on a map:</p>
     Latitude: <input type="number" id="in_lat"> Longitude: <input type="number" id="in_lon">
     <p><input type="button" id="btn_2" onclick="find_location()" value="Show"></p>
     <p id="output"></p>
     <div id="map"></div>
     <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
     <script>
     var x = document.getElementById("output");
     var y = document.querySelector("#btn").value;
        
     function init() {
      var z = document.getElementById("btn") 
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(z, "click", get_location);
     }
        
     function get_location() {
      if (y == "Where am I?") {
      document.querySelector("#btn").value = "Update";
      }
        
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_position, show_error);
      } 
      else { 
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by your browser.";
      }
     }
        
     function show_position(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      var altitude = (position.coords.altitude == null) ? "Data not available" : altitude;
        
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + latitude + 
      "<br>Longitude: " + longitude +
      "<br>Accuracy: " + position.coords.accuracy +
      "<br>Altitude: " + altitude;
        
      alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude); //<------------offending method
      display_map(latitude, longitude);
     }
        
     function display_map(lat, lon) {
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
      var map_prop = {
      center:point,
      zoom:5,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
        
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),map_prop);
        
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:point,
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
     }
        
     function show_error(error) {
      switch(error.code) {
      case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
      case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
      case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
      case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
      break;
      }
      document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "Oops something went wrong";
     }
        
     function find_location() {
      var latitude_in = document.getElementById("in_lat").value;
      var longitude_in = document.getElementById("in_lon").value; 
        
      if (latitude_in.length <= 0 || longitude_in.length <= 0) {
      alert("Please enter values correctly");
      }
      else {
      var latitude = Number(latitude_in).toFixed(7);
      var longitude = Number(longitude_in).toFixed(7);
      alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + latitude + 
      "<br>Longitude: " + longitude;
      display_map(latitude, longitude);
      }
     }
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo in your code.  You are adding the "click" event listener to the button twice.

Once in the HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="get_location()" value="Where am I?">
```

Once in the JavaScript:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(z, "click", get_location);
```

That makes the `get_location` function fire twice for each click on the button.  Remove one of them and it will work as you expect.

**code snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GPS coordinates to map TEST</title>
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 500px;
      height: 380px;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Click below to get your coordinates and display your current position on a map:</p>
  <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="get_location()" value="Where am I?">
  <p>Or provide coordinates to display the position entered on a map:</p>
  Latitude: <input type="number" id="in_lat"> Longitude: <input type="number" id="in_lon">
  <p><input type="button" id="btn_2" onclick="find_location()" value="Show"></p>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
  <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("output");
    var y = document.querySelector("#btn").value;

    function get_location() {
      if (y == "Where am I?") {
        document.querySelector("#btn").value = "Update";
      }

      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_position, show_error);
      } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by your browser.";
      }
    }

    function show_position(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      var altitude = (position.coords.altitude == null) ? "Data not available" : altitude;

      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + longitude +
        "<br>Accuracy: " + position.coords.accuracy +
        "<br>Altitude: " + altitude;
      alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude); //<------------offending method
      display_map(latitude, longitude);
    }

    function display_map(lat, lon) {
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
      var map_prop = {
        center: point,
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), map_prop);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
    }

    function show_error(error) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
          break;
      }
      document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "Oops something went wrong";
    }

    function find_location() {
      var latitude_in = document.getElementById("in_lat").value;
      var longitude_in = document.getElementById("in_lon").value;

      if (latitude_in.length <= 0 || longitude_in.length <= 0) {
        alert("Please enter values correctly");
      } else {
        var latitude = Number(latitude_in).toFixed(7);
        var longitude = Number(longitude_in).toFixed(7);
        alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + latitude +
          "<br>Longitude: " + longitude;
        display_map(latitude, longitude);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```